# Why Guard doesn't work in nested route - Angular 5

Tags: angular, angular5, angular-routing

I've created Guards for protection against entry to pages with insufficient permissions.

But I wondering, why I'm forced to add Guards on each route. I thought that guard on 1st route should be sufficient as **children are lazy loaded**. But it's not. Am I doing something wrong, or this is how Angular works?

*app.routing.ts*

```
export const routes: Routes = [
    { path: "", component: HomeComponent },
    { path: "groups", loadChildren: "app/main/main.module#MainModule",
        canLoad: [AuthCanLoadGuard] } // <-- guard on first route
];
```

Children:

*main.routing.ts*

```
export const routes: Routes = [
    { path: "groups", component: GroupListComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
    { path: "groups/:id/category", component: CategoryComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
    {
        path: "groups/:id/category", component: GroupSummaryComponent, children: [
            { path: "bikes", canLoad: [AuthCanLoadGuard], loadChildren: "app/features/bikes/bikes.module#BikesModule" },
            { path: "cars", canLoad: [AuthCanLoadGuard] loadChildren: "app/features/cars/cars.module#CarsModule" },
        ]
    }
];
```

As you can see in *main.routing.ts* I had to add guards to all routes to make it work. Why is that?

---

EDIT:

I've debugged and it seems that is not entering to AuthCanLoadGuard for MainModule. However for BikesModule and CarsModule works fine. But I don't know why...

---

EDIT 2:

Problem solved. Problem was with route configuration.

1. Make sure you're not importing MainModule into AppModule (that's why I could have `groups` in path in *main.routing.ts* what is wrong since parent had `group` already)
2. RouterModule.forRoot in Main.Module should be forChild

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try canActivateChildren instead. I'm not really sure what good canLoad is for, never used it.

Edit: your child routes look wrong too though. They shouldn't star with 'groups' because that part is caught in the parent. So in main.routing `{ path: "groups",` should be `{ path: "",` etc

Comment: Didn't help. Btw. whilst using canLoad - modules aren't loading in explorer so is good for security. That's why I used it.

Comment: If I remove `groups` from path then https://localhost:4002 navigate me to screen with groups.

Comment: Sounds like you're calling RouterModule.forRoot in Main. Should be forChild

Comment: And make sure you're not importing MainModule into AppModule

Comment: And one more comment, there's no such thing as client side security. A hacker can get your JS code no matter what you do :)

Comment: "And make sure you're not importing MainModule into AppModule" omg it was the problem... It's easy to miss it :/ Thank you so much!